# Prove $\frac{1}{N!}\varepsilon_{i_1\dots i_N}\varepsilon_{j_1\dots j_N}A_{i_1 j_1}\dots A_{i_N j_N} = \det A$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, determinant, tensors

Is there any simple way to prove the following:

$$\frac{1}{N!}\varepsilon_{i_1\dots i_N}\varepsilon_{j_1\dots j_N}A_{i_1 j_1}\dots A_{i_N j_N} = \det A. \tag{$1$} $$

Comment: One would hope not, since it is not true. Perhaps you mean the sum of all such terms?

Comment: To give OP the benefit of the doubt he may be using the Einstein convention in which a repeated index implies a summation over the range of the index. http://mathworld.wolfram.com/EinsteinSummation.html